# iPhone Browser emulator with orientation detection

Tags: iphone, browser, emulation, mobile-website

I'm looking for an iPhone browser emulator like [iBBDemo2](http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/) for Windows. But since [iBBDemo](http://code.google.com/p/ibbdemo2/) doesn't seem to support orientation (yes, its rotatable but this information is not send to the server as the iPhone does, to use this information in the Website's JavaScript), I'm looking for an alternative.

Or are there any windows based full iPhone emulators like the ones for Android without commercial Apple Developer registration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new emulator from Electric Plum (free light version). It's pro version seems to support rotation events in JavaScript.

http://www.electricplum.com/products.html

Answer (score 3):

There's a free tool (Chrome Extension) called **[Ripple](http://ripple.tinyhippos.com/)** (which was bought by RIM):

> Test and debug your HTML5 mobile applications for multiple platforms.
> All from within your browser and in a fraction of the time.

Not sure how well it works in emulator device quirks.  But it does have the rotation change option.

Comment: If your website (that you test with Ripple) is not visible from internet, then your ajax calls (tunnelled through its' own server) will not work.